# Will being denied entry influence my dependent visa request?

Tags: ireland

I am applying for a dependent visa for Ireland as my spouse is already there working on a critical skill visa. I did my masters degree and was on a valid work visa living in Northern Ireland (UK). I wanted to visit a branch of my home church in Dublin and was misinformed that since I hold a valid UK visa it is not required for me to apply for an Irish visa, so I went ahead without applying for one.
It was my fault as I didn't crosscheck this information.

It was a Sunday morning and I was just carrying my bible and a wallet and boarded the bus to Dublin from Belfast where I was living. The border police stopped the bus and checked everyones travel documents, unfortunately I wasn't carrying mine. The police were very kind and courteous and understood I wasn't lying. However, they politely denied me entry. My finger prints were scanned and a letter was given to me which mentioned the entry was refused due to lack of appropriate travel documents (Visa and passport)<sup>*</sup>. Will this affect my chances of getting the dependent visa to Ireland?

<sup>* I've misplaced the letter unfortunately. This was over four years ago.</sup>

Comment: @Paulmathews2222 What did the letter say?

Comment: @Jan Doggen, my finger prints were scanned and then a letter was given to me which mentioned the entry was refused due to lack of appropriate travel documents (Visa and passport).

Comment: @Traveller, I've misplaced the letter unfortunately. This was over four years ago. If my memory serves right; It mentioned that my entry was refused as I wasn't carrying any travel documents (Passport & Visa).

Comment: I most certainly will mention this on the visa application.

Comment: I was on a post study work visa. Unfortunately this category type requires a visa to enter Ireland, which I didn't know. I certainly will mention this on the visa application. What chances or under what circumstances they might reject if they do? Since I do not have the letter, will they overlook it if I mention the factual reason?

Comment: This question is about a long-term stay so is probably best asked on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/